# How to query the terminal state that is set by escape sequences such as tput smam?

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

QEMU was [leaving my terminal in a weird state](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/issues/110) and it took me a while to finally debug it to the precise capability in question: `tput smam` vs `tput rmam`.

Is there a way to inspect the current terminal state, hopefully showing the current value of all capabilities at once?

This would allow me to easily diff out a working vs a "broken" terminal to find out what was modified.

Finding out the current state of any specific capability would also be a good start though, e.g. `smam` vs `rmam`.

Tested in Ubuntu 19.10, Gnome terminal.

Answer (score 5):

This might work (VTE implements part of this control):

> [**`CSI ?`** *Ps* **`$ p`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Ps-$-p.1D6D)
>
> Request DEC private mode (DECRQM).  For VT300 and up, reply
>   DECRPM is
>
> CSI ? *Ps* ; *Pm* $ y
>
> where Ps is the mode number as in DECSET/DECSET, Pm is the
>             mode value as in the ANSI DECRQM.

specifically, *Ps* is 7:

> ```
>        Ps = 7  ⇒  Auto-wrap Mode (DECAWM), VT100.
> ```

which corresponds to the settings used in the [terminal description](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/terminfo-contents.html#tic-xterm-basic):

> `rmam=\E[?7l,`
>   `smam=\E[?7h,`

so... you'd do

```
printf '\033[?7$p'
```

and expect to get back

```
\033[?7;1$y
```

or

```
\033[?7;2$y
```

depending on whether the mode was set or reset, respectively.

This also assumes your script/program is reading from the *terminal* (not necessarily *standard input*).  There are several [test/demo scripts](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/tree/master/vttests) in xterm's sources which you might find useful reading (though most will not work with VTE).  Generally I'd test this feature with [vttest](https://invisible-island.net/vttest/vttest.html#link_tools), which has been packaged for whatever system you're using.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion Thomas, but I'm afraid it didn't seem to work on my system: `printf '\033[?7$p' | hd` produces `1b 5b 3f 37 24 70  |.[?7$p|` both after `tput smam` and `tput rmam`.

Comment: Perhaps you're not reading from the terminal - I added a clarification.  But piping through `hd` doesn't sound as if you're writing **to** the terminal.

Comment: Given the `| hd` the easier conclusion is that xe is not _writing to_ the terminal.  (-:

Comment: @Ciro if you want `hd`, do it like this: `(g=$(stty -g); stty -icanon -echo min 0 time 5; printf '\033[?7$p'; dd count=1 2>/dev/null | hexdump -C; stty "$g")`. That escape doesn't work in `screen` or `tmux`.

Comment: @mosvy ah, actually yes, it works without `| hd`. I thought I had tried that yesterday, oh well. But good to know how to obtain it programatically as you showed, since the end goal would be to generate a human readable list of all properties in one go.

Answer (score 3):

To *complement* [Thomas Dickey's helpful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558774/54804), which provides all crucial information with POSIX-compliant **convenience function** `tmode`, adapted from the helpful command in [mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy)'s comment:

Given a terminal mode number, it prints `'SET'` or `'RESET'` to reflect the mode's status; e.g.:

```bash
# Get status of the DECAWM (autowrap) mode
$ tmode 7
RESET
```

**CAVEATS:**

If anyone can shed more light on these, please comment.

- The function **works only in *certain* terminal emulators**, notably *not* in Gnome Terminal:

  - macOS: `iTerm2.app`, but not the built-in `Terminal.app`
  - Ubuntu: `XTerm` and `UXTerm`, but not the standard Gnome `Terminal`
  - Windows (WSL): *not* supported; neither in a legacy console window nor in Windows Terminal.
- Re supported **mode numbers** :

  - The [console_codes(4) Linux `man` page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) in section **"DEC Private Mode (DECSET/DECRST) sequences"** mentions only 1, 3, 5..9, 25 and 1000
  - In *practice*, the terminal emulates mentioned above return meaningful values for the following:

    - `iTerm2.app` on macOS: 1..3, 5..8, 25, 40..41, 45, 47, 69, 1000
    - `[U]XTerm` on Ubuntu: 1..7, 9, 12, 18..19, 25, 30, 35, 38, 40..42, 44..45, 47, 66..67, 69, 80, 95, 1000
  - There are other, ***non-numeric* modes** mentioned in the linked `man` page, such as `=` (`DECPAM`) and `>` (`DECPNM`) - I don't know how to query those.
  - While [Thomas Dickey's link](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Ps-$-p.1D6D) to the explanation of the DEC private-mode escape sequences mentions return value `0` as indicating an unknown mode and `3` / `4` as "permanently set/reset"; in practice it seems to be `4` that indicates a unknown mode, with known modes only ever reporting `1` ("set", i.e. on) or `2` ("reset", i.e. off).

**Shell function `tmode`**:

```bash
#! /bin/sh -

tmode() (

  [ "$#" -eq 1 ] || { echo "Usage: tmode <mode-number>" >&2; return 2; }
  modeNum="$1"

  # Redirect stdin and stdout temporarily to the controlling terminal.
  # This is necessary so that invocation such as `result=$(tmode 1)` work.
  {
    stty_settings="$(stty -g)"
    stty -icanon -echo min 0 time 5
    # Query the terminal.
    printf '\33[?%s$p' "$modeNum"
    result=$(dd count=1)
    stty "$stty_settings"
  } <> /dev/tty >&0 2> /dev/null
  
  # Activate this to visiualize the raw result.
  # printf %s "$result" | od -t x1 -t c > /dev/tty

  # Print a friendly result.
  case $result in
    *';1$'*)
     echo SET;;
    *';2$'*)
     echo RESET;; 
    # NOTE: It seems that 4 is only ever used to signal a nonexistent mode.
    # *';3$'*)
    #  echo PERMANENTLY SET;; 
    # *';4$'*)
    #  echo PERMANENTLY RESET;; 
    *)
      echo "Unknown mode: $modeNum" >&2;;
  esac
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### set mode

ESC [ Ⓝ h
ESC [ ? Ⓝ h

### reset mode  //unset

ESC [ Ⓝ l
ESC [ ? Ⓝ l

### request mode  //query state

ESC [ Ⓝ $ p
ESC [ ? Ⓝ $ p

Ⓝ is a decimal number (the mode number)

### test in shell

```bash
#set
echo -ne '\e[?1049h'

#query = set
echo -ne '\e[?1049$p'; cat
^[[?1049;1$y

#reset
echo -ne '\e[?1049l'

#query = not set
echo -ne '\e[?1049$p'; cat
^[[?1049;2$y
```

### refs

xterm docs: DECRQM DECRQM

https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#:~:text=DECRQM

NOTE: use chrome access can scroll to highlight keyword in webpage

control sequences
https://terminalguide.namepad.de/seq/

mode list
https://terminalguide.namepad.de/mode/

set mode
https://terminalguide.namepad.de/seq/csi_sh/
https://terminalguide.namepad.de/seq/csi_sh__p/

request mode
https://terminalguide.namepad.de/seq/csi_sp_t_dollar/
https://terminalguide.namepad.de/seq/csi_sp__p_t_dollar/

vt100 docs
https://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECRQM.html
https://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECRPM.html
https://vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/chapter4.html#S4.6